# D integrating with C library causes gibberish to be output

Tags: c, d

I have a C library which has something like below:

## Abc.h file

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t dbtype;
    uint32_t dbcount;
} Abc;

void test_string(Abc* abcobj, char* strA, char* strB);
Abc* create_abc(void);
```

## Abc.c

```
void test_string(Abc* abcobj, char* strA, char* strB)
{
    printf("Str A is %s and str B is %s\n", strA, strB);
    return;
}

Abc* create_abc()
{
    Abc* abcobj;
    abcobj = (Abc*) calloc(1, sizeof(Abc));
    return abcobj;
}
```

Now, I am trying to call these functions in my D code.

## testD.d

```
module testD;

import std.stdio;
import core.stdc.string;
import core.sys.posix.dlfcn;

extern (C)
{
    struct Abc {
        ubyte dbtype;
        int dbcount;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto lib = dlopen("Abc.so".ptr, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);

    if (lib is null) {
        return -1;
    }

    void function(Abc* abcobj, char* strA, char* strB) test_string = cast(void function(Abc* abcobj, char* strA, char* strB))dlsym(lib, "test_string");
    Abc* function() create_abc = cast(Abc* function())dlsym(lib, "create_abc");

    char* strA = cast(char*)("this is string one");
    char* strB = cast(char*)("this is string two");

    Abc* abcobj = create_abc();
    test_string(abcobj, strA, strB);

    if (dlclose(lib) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
} // main() function
```

I compile the testD.d using:

dmd testD.d

Then run the ./testD

When the test_string outputs the sentence, the value for strA always comes out as gibberish while strB comes out just fine.

Why is this happening??

Comment: Some other things: `dbcount` should be a `uint` in D to match `uint32_t` in C, and `test_string` should accept `const char*` since the strings don't need to be modified (and casting D string literals of type `immutable(char)[]` to `char*` is technically undefined behavior).

Comment: Have changed the type to uint and using const char* now.

Casting part have changed to char* strA = "this is string one".dup.ptr;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `.so` was made with `C`, you've compiled the library with `C` linkage, however when you're importing the symbols, you're discarding the fact, which means that `D` tries to use the `D` calling convention to invoke the code, which is different from the `C` calling convention.

When you import the functions, you need to specify this, so the `dlsym` lines need to look like:

```
extern (C) void function(Abc* abcobj, char* strA, char* strB) test_string =
    cast(void function(Abc* abcobj, char* strA, char* strB))dlsym(lib, "test_string");
extern (C) Abc* function() create_abc =
    cast(Abc* function())dlsym(lib, "create_abc");
```

Once you get the calling convention right, the correct results should come out from the call.